# If I need add unschedule before schedule and scheduleOnce?

Tags: cocos2d-x, schedule

[image]

Why each schedule I always need add the unschedle ?
Why cocos2dx don't auto remove before schedule selector ??

Comment: If you want to know 'why' ask the developers. In cocos2d-iphone it used to be an assertion, now it's a warning message. It shouldn't even be that. It's easy enough to fix by changing the schedule method in question to perform a corresponding unschedule first.

Comment: thx, now I fix the problem by add unschedule. :P